# Image Picker Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using the UIImagePickerController to take a picture, that works great, but do not want to use the stand image editor, instead I want to use my own custom image editor.  I want to transition to that after I take the picture.  I am using the method below to push a view controller after the image picker dismisses.

However, I want to push this before the image picker dismiss to avoid an awkward transition.  Any ideas?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image picker is already in a navigation interface, so you can push anything you like onto the image picker as a secondary (editing) interface:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* im = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if (!im)
        return;
    SecondViewController* svc =
        [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil image:im];
    [picker pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

You will, however, have to interfere to prevent the image picker from navigating to its *own* secondary interface. The easy way to do that is to set `picker.showsCameraControls = NO` and substitute your own controls.

Also, I might be wrong about this, but since you are the navigation controller delegate I think you can just veto an attempt by the image picker to navigate to its own secondary interface. (EDIT: No, I guess not, sorry. The delegate gets a `will` and a `did` but not a `should` message.)

Comment: I didn't want to lose the camera buttons at the top, such as the flash buton

Comment: OK, made another (more tentative) suggestion.

Comment: I think your answer might be the correct way to go, i'm going to wait, and see if anyone else has suggestions though